# Парсинг JSON

Tags: json, php

Подскажите решение, как на PHP спарсить JSON, в котором попадаются подобного рода вещи:

```
{"accDo": "a:2:{s:3:"get";s:1:"1";s:4:"take";s:1:"1";}"}
```

Стандартные средства возвращают ошибку синтаксиса.

Comment: [json_encode()][1]?

   [1]:http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php

Comment: как раз проблема с json_decode.

Comment: @nddd, кто генерирует json?

Comment: понятия не имею, я беру его в виде строки из базы.

Comment: да, именно так. Но что делать?

Comment: @nddd, Проврьте - есть ли у вас где-то обработка с помощью stripcslashes().

Comment: проблема в том, что таких записей уже полно, и их терять нельзя.
Подскажите решение, если не сложно )

Comment: @nddd, боюсь, что в таком случае, вам придётся прибегнуть к регуляркам. Диагноз не окончателен, но вполне возможно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[[[@nddd](/users/15724/nddd)](/users/15724/nddd)](/users/15724/nddd)](/users/15724/nddd), догадываюсь, в чём проблемка. Было примерно следующее:

```
$arr = array (
    'accDo' => array ( 'get' => '1', 'take' => '1', )
);
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
    $arr[$k] = serialize($v);
}
```

Результат:

```
{"accDo":"a:2:{s:3:\"get\";s:1:\"1\";s:4:\"take\";s:1:\"1\";}"}
```

Слэши были удалены или перед внесением в БД, или уже после вывода. 
 Кто вообще додумался преобразовывать двумя методами?..

**Обновление**

[[[[@nddd](/users/15724/nddd)](/users/15724/nddd)](/users/15724/nddd)](/users/15724/nddd), по регуляркам на форуме есть более компетентные люди, но пока могу предложить такой вариант:

```
// Исходная строка
$wrongStr = '{"accDo":"a:2:{s:3:"get";s:1:"1";s:4:"take";s:1:"1";}"}';
// К сериализованной части применяем addslashes()
$normalStr = preg_replace_callback(
    '/a:\d+:([^}]+)}/',
    create_function(
        '$matches',
        'return addslashes($matches[0]);'
    ),
    $wrongStr
);
// декодирование
$arr = json_decode($normalStr, 1);
print_r( unserialize($arr['accDo']) );
```

Результат

```
Array
(
    [get] => 1
    [take] => 1
)
```

Но повторюсь, что регулярку хорошо бы доработать

Comment: Благодарю, это решение то что нужно. )